# AS3: Disposing of cacheAsBitmap bitmaps?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, bitmap

I've got a large, detailed, interactive vector object with dynamic text that will frequently translate horizontally from off the screen onto the screen when the user needs to look at it, then back off the screen when the user is done. If I set myVector.cacheAsBitmap = true before translating it and myVector.cacheAsBitmap = false after translating it, what happens to all of those bitmaps that are generated each time? Do I have to dispose of them myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe help about [Bitmap caching](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36c11f3d612431904db9-7ffc.html):

> Turning on bitmap caching for an animated object that contains complex
>   vector graphics (such as text or gradients) improves performance.
>   However, if bitmap caching is enabled on a display object such as a
>   movie clip that has its timeline playing, you get the opposite result.
>   On each frame, the runtime must update the cached bitmap and then
>   redraw it onscreen, which requires many CPU cycles. The bitmap caching
>   feature is an advantage only when the cached bitmap can be generated
>   once and then used without the need to update it.
>
> If you turn on bitmap caching for a Sprite object, the object can be
>   moved without causing the runtime to regenerate the cached bitmap.
>   Changing the x and y properties of the object does not cause
>   regeneration. However, any attempt to rotate it, scale it, or change
>   its alpha value causes the runtime to regenerate the cached bitmap,
>   and as a result, hurts performance.

**Conclusion**

If you make a simple translational movement along the x or y axis, your bitmap is created only one time.

**Do I have to dispose of them myself?**

It seems that you can't touch the bitmap cache only used internally by Flash player.